Pipe/Vent sound in house
Recently moved into our home and I’ve noticed a sound that’s kinda of like a banging metallic sound in the wall. I’m thinking it could be pipes? Possibly vents? I don’t think it’s dripping water as it sounds too solid and I don’t hear any ripple or splash.
It seems to happen more frequently at night, but it’s evenly spaced. I timed it one night at 1 minute 7 seconds intervals, another night at 1 minute 32 seconds and once in the day time at 3 minutes 23 seconds.
Our heat and ac haven’t been used in weeks, and the noise is loudest upstairs against the bedroom wall. You can hear it faintly outside the wall and just barely downstairs.
The plumbing vent pipe does seem to run down the wall where I’m hearing the noise and there is the HVAC vent on that side of the house.
I’ve attached a link to the sound here, I’m recording in the room so hard to hear.
The Sound
Anyone have an idea what may be causing it?

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

The timing is very odd for a plumbing source, since you need water moving/stopping(using a sink/toilet/tub).

possible thermal expansion/contraction

I considered thermal expansion/contraction but I wouldn’t expect it to occur at consistent intervals
